# Clicking a button's pseudo-element in Firefox does not trigger click

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title suggests, clicking a button's pseudo-element in Firefox does not trigger click for me.

Also, text and elements beneath the pseudo-element are still interactive.  See fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/15bmz7zg/1/

I'm on Firefox 58.0.1 - Mac.  Tested fiddle on Chrome and Safari and all works as expected.  Preparing to submit a bug report, but figured I'd first see if anyone else agrees: **This is a bug, right?**

UPDATE 7/19/18
Suggested duplicate does not address this problem.  I've since filed a Firefox bug report, and the bug was confirmed.  I'll add an answer reflecting this.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
 document.querySelector('button').classList.toggle('overlay')
})
```

```css
button.overlay::after{
  content:"";
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(128,128,128,.5);
}
```

```html
<h2>
I shouldn't be able to select this text when overlay is active.
</h2>
<p>
And, clicking the overlay should trigger button click.
</p>
<button>
toggle overlay
</button>
```

Comment: Starting a question with "Also"? What is that in addition to?

Comment: the title... I'll copy/pasta

Comment: I'm on the latest version of Firefox 58.0.1 (quantum) and your fiddle works as expected. Could you check again after updating?

Comment: @Seth I also tried on FF 58.0.01 on Windows 10 but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: @Seth - updated the question to reflect I'm also on I'm on Firefox 58.0.1 - Mac OS.

Comment: I think problem is with `button`, because it seems working for any other element, but using `div` instead of `button` is weird :( Still didn't work in FF 61.0 @ macOS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FireFox Button child span and li not clickable or hoverable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275749/firefox-button-child-span-and-li-not-clickable-or-hoverable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Firefox, confirmed by my bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1435331
... which was marked as a duplicate of this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1089326

The bug is 4 years old, but apparently is being worked on now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your overlay as a non-pseudo-element

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
 document.querySelector('.overlay-wrap').classList.add('showed')
});
document.querySelector('.overlay-wrap').addEventListener('click', function(){
 this.classList.remove('showed')
});
```

```css
.overlay-wrap {
  display: none;
}
.overlay-wrap.showed{
  content:"";
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(128,128,128,.5);
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<h2>
I shouldn't be able to select this text when overlay is active.
</h2>
<p>
And, clicking the overlay should trigger button click.
</p>
<button>
toggle overlay

</button>
<span class="overlay-wrap"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!  yeah, there are a few different alternatives, but my original code _should_ work if I'm reading the spec right, and the original code is more elegant/flexible to me.  I'd like to use it if it's valid, and wait for Firefox to post a fix, if it's indeed a bug.